# PHP usort() for Dummies

Tags: php

Sorry for posting this totally confused n00b question, but I do not get around the arcane `usort()` explanation in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

usort($a, "cmp");

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
?>
```

When i `echo $a` in the `cmp` function I get a `5156120` as key for the first item, when I `echo $b` I get `2535630`.

That is basically my whole question: What is `$a` and `$b` in the callback function?
But if you want to really help, please give a "line-by-line" explanation about what is happening.

HAPPY NYE!!!

(I tried to add the tags "noob" and "confused", need 1400 reputation more though. ; )

Comment: You must have something going on that's not in the code above b/c when I add `echo 'a=>'.$a.'<br>','b=>'.$b.'<br>';` as the first line of the cmp function, I get the values of the array, as expected.  What the usort function does is go through each pairing of elements and compare them, sorting them as it goes along.

Comment: Not exactly each pairing @JeremyMiller

Comment: Each, unique pairing is what I found by executing the code.  So, it would do 3 against 2, but not duplicate the effort by doing 2 against 3.  Did I miss something?

Comment: Check first answer here for example, there all compared pairs shown for one sample case @JeremyMiller

Comment: @Cthulhu Fair enough, the minimum number of comparisons necessary to form an ordering of all elements. :)  Great explanation. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$a` and `$b` are the two values being compared in the custom comparison function.

If you have `array( 3, 2, 5, 6, 1)` that you're sorting, you'll find `cmp()` compares 3 to 2, 2 to 5, 5 to 6, etc. until the values are properly sorted.

So, for example:

```
<?php

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    echo "$a :compared with: $b <br/>";
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$arr = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

usort($arr, "cmp");
```

outputs:

```
5 :compared with: 2
5 :compared with: 3
5 :compared with: 6
1 :compared with: 5
2 :compared with: 1
3 :compared with: 2
```

I see `usort()` usually used to make much more intricate comparisons, where you need to break apart the value and compare just a piece of it, or assign custom priorities (e.g. sort by title President, Vice President, Secretary, etc., by *priority* and not by alphanumeric value)

Comment: $a is also the array that's passed to usort(). That's probably part of the OP's confusion.

Comment: Good point! You might substitute `$array` for `$a` variable beginning with `$array = array(3, 2...` and until the end of the code block.

Comment: That codesample comes straight off the php docpage, it would indeed be less confusing for new users if they'd given the array variable another name..

Comment: @fvu Sorry for coming back only now to all, had to get into the new year. ;) I sorted the actual confusion about the `$a` out already, but that lead me in the end to asking here, because then the mysticism about the `$b` spread out to `$a` in the function, since nothing is passed. So I agree to changing the `$a`in the manual for the array and please giving some information about the `$a` and `$b` inside the function in the description. ;)

Comment: @dollarvar many languages I know offer a sort and/or search function with a pluggable comparator, and they all use a comparator function very similar to the one used by php - check out C's [qsort](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort), or Java's [Arrays.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T[],%20java.util.Comparator%29).  I can only assume that the php people assumed that therefore their solution would be "obvious enough" :)